# Add class in the top element when i click on button in a list with the same classes - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

when I click the button btn-top-heart of an item, I have to add the class to the panel-title .heart-right, but only .heart-right item of the single box of the clicked button.
i'm not familiar with jquery i do not even know if it is possible. I would not use a .click function for every #div

```js
$(".btn-top-heart").click(function() {
  $(".heart-right").addClass('red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      Test 1
      <span class="heart-right"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </h4>
    <button class="btn-top-heart">
      <a href="mailto:aaa@aaa.com">Sell</a>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      Test 2
      <span class="heart-right"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </h4>
    <button class="btn-top-heart">
      <a href="mailto:aaa@aaa.com">Sell</a>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      Test 3
      <span class="heart-right"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </h4>
    <button class="btn-top-heart">
      <a href="mailto:aaa@aaa.com">Sell</a>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      Test 4
      <span class="heart-right"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </h4>
    <button class="btn-top-heart">
      <a href="mailto:aaa@aaa.com">Sell</a>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      Test 5
      <span class="heart-right"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </h4>
    <button class="btn-top-heart">
      <a href="mailto:aaa@aaa.com">Sell</a>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

someone can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

This code will work:

```
$('.btn-top-heart').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('li').find('.heart-right').addClass('red');
});
```